# Django Inheritance and Permalinks

Tags: python, django, inheritance, subclass, permalinks

I'm creating a simple CMS in django, with multiple "modules" (each as a django app). I've set up the following models:

```
class FooObject(models.Model):
    id = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User, editable=False, related_name="createdby")

class FooPage(FooObject):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('page', (), {'page_id':self.id}

class FooSubitem(FooObject):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(FooPage, related_name='subitems')
```

In each of the modules, I create a subclass of FooPage, and at least one subclass of FooSubitem, e.g.

```
# in FooBlog.models
class FooBlog(FooPage):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User, editable=False)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog', (), {'blog_id':self.id})

class FooPost(FooSubitem):
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and

```
# in FooGallery.models
class FooGallery(FooPage):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('gallery', (), {'gallery_id':self.id})

class FooImage(FooSubitem):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='foogallery')
```

These are simplifications, but should give you a good idea of what I'm trying to do. In the admins for FooPost and FooImage, I restrict the parent selection list to their corresponding parent pages.

My problem arises when I try to use these in a template. In each view, I have the following:

```
page_list = FooPage.objects.all()
```

which returns a list of all FooPages, of both FooBlog and FooGallery types. However, when I iterate through this list:

```
{% for page in page_list %}{{ page.get_absolute_url }}{% endfor %}
```

it returns the 'page' url pattern, not the 'blog' or 'gallery' url pattern.

How do I make this work without having to rewrite the code when I want to add a FooCalendar module later on? I want to make sure this works with any possible module.

Thanks,

- Lexo

Comment: It's odd that it doesn't use the subclasses function for returning the url (It does return FooBlog and FooGallery within the list, right) .. perhaps you may need to set the `FooBlog` and `FooGallery` classes as proxy models. Proxy models are used when you keep the same database for the models, but you want to adjust things like ordering, and perhaps the `get_absolute_url` functionality. Check them out: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#id8 -- Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look into proxy models.

Comment: I don't think proxy models are what I need. The individual subclasses such as FooImage need to have extra fields attached to them. Abstract classes would be perfect, but I need the parent/child relationship between FooPages and FooSubitems to be there, and you can't specify foreign keys on abstract classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic solution to this problem tends to be [adding a ContentType to the superclass which stores the type of subclass for that instance](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1031/). This way you can rely on a consistent API that returns the related subclass object of the appropriate type.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I ended up modifying the "QuerySet Hack" described in the comments of your link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid adding a content type field by using the InheritanceManager from [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/).

Then, if you call `.select_subclasses` on a queryset, it will downcast all of the objects, for example:

```
FooPage.objects.select_subclasses().all()
```

Answer (score 0):

`FooPage.objects.all()` returns all the objects of type `FooPage`, these objects will be mix of underlying db table rows for FooPage, FooBlog, FooGallery. To get the correct URL you should get the FooBlog or FooGallery object e.g.

```
page.fooblog.get_absolute_url()
```

it may throw `FooBlog.DoesNotExist` error if page is simply a page object i.e created via FooPage, so to get correct urls you may do something like this

```
   urls = []
   for page in FooPage.objects.all():
        try:
            page = page.fooblog
        except FooBlog.DoesNotExist:
            pass

            urls.append(page.get_absolute_url())
```

alternatively you may try to make FooPage a abstractclass if you do not want FooPage to be a real table.

Comment: Thanks Anurag. My problem is that I don't know which module apps (e.g. FooBlog, FooGallery) I will have installed, or may install in the future. If I end up creating 10 or more different apps (which is entirely possible) I don't want to have to re-write my code to include checks for each type of FooPage. Plus, that seems terribly inefficient and something that I should be able to do programmatically.

Is there a way to "drill down" to the most specific subclass?

Comment: Also, I tried using abstract classes but since FooSubitems need to have FooPage parents, and you can't specify a foreign key to an abstract class, it doesn't work.

Comment: may be you can write a generic function which does the same thing, i.e. try to get derived class objects if possible, you can do that using a custom model manager (http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/custom_managers/)